# My code keeps running twice in discord.py Cogs

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm unsure if I'm using cogs correctly, or if that would even affect the bot running commands twice, although all of my commands run twice only when I use a command. I believe the issue is coming from the program checking if I ran the command twice?

This only happens in commands, and not listeners.

There is only one instance of the bot running on my computer, i double checked it. I'll add more code to this question if people need it.

sense I keep getting errors like this:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "tf" is not found
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "tf" is not found
```

Here is some of the broken code

```
class general_commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases = ['c', 'clear'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
    async def clean(self, ctx, amount: int):
        amount += 1
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
        amount -= 1
        msg = f"You've deleted {amount} messages"
        await ctx.send(msg, delete_after = 5)
```

Comment: Um, the command isn't found... that's what the error is telling you. Why are you calling a command that you haven't coded or showed us?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running the script more than once? If you're using an IDE (like vscode or pycharm) that can happen easily, you can open the task manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc` for windows) and look for hidden python processes, kill them. You can close the editor or restart your PC altogether.

Comment: I was showing you that the command was being checked twice, even if i run a command that I have coded, it runs twice.


I've checked through my task manager multiple times, and there is only one running python script.  I've tried restarting, moving the files to different directories ,etc. It really only started when I moved my commands into Cogs.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code below, I had process_commands called, which made the bot run through the commands a second time each time a message was sent. Whoops.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            for word in filtered_words:
                if word in ctx.content:
                    await ctx.delete()

            #random xp gain
```

Comment: You ran process_commands again? It would only run twice here if process_commands was found twice.

Comment: sense the commands were in cogs, I didn't need process_commands, which is something I read before I just completely missed it when reformatting my bot. and after deleting the line it worked fine.

Comment: No, you do need process_commands in on_message. Unless you have an extra on_message in your Cogs you need it. Which I see that you do oops

Comment: Yeah I just blanked during that

Comment: There's a difference between listeners and events in discord.py. listeners are functions that you decorate with either `commands.Cog.listener` or `bot.listen`, events are decorated with `bot.event` (you can only have one event, but multiple listeners). You do **not** use `process_commands` in listeners, only in the event.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh, ok. So when I was rewriting I changed my events into listeners that's what messed me up.